# Separated tables for two sets with the same generic type in an Entity JPA Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, set

In my application I have the Person entity which has two lists properties with the same types:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Person implements Serializable {
    /* ...something... */
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Group> myGroups = new HashSet<>();
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Group> belongToGroups = new HashSet<>();
```

and Group entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groupp")
public class Group implements Serializable {
    /* ...something... */
}
```

And in my database then, I have table named: **person_groupp** and there I have columns like:

**Person_id, myGroups_id, belongToGroups_id**

### And my question is, how to separate these Sets into two, separated tables?

like:
**Person_myGroups** and **Person_belongToGroups**

Now, after saving one of them I receive exception like this, because another value is null and has no default value:

> java.sql.SQLException: Field 'belongToGroups_id' doesn't have a default value

It would be much better for me to make two tables instead of joined one. I am sure it is easy but can't find the way to do it.

Comment: If the association from `Person` to `Group` is indeed a **One**-to-Many, then why do you need a join table for My Groups? If a `Group` has one `Person` as it's 'owner' then there should be a person ID in Group, and a `@ManyToOne` from `Group` to `Person`. Then the `@OneToMany` in `Person` can use a `mappedBy`. That way, your join table will only be needed for the actual `@ManyToMany` belongsToGroups.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as I thought, was very, very simple
@JoinTable(name = "somename") on every collection creates 2 separated tables.